# How to apply l2 normalization to a layer in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, lambda, keras, neural-network, normalization

I am trying to normalize a layer in my neural network using l2 normalization. I want to divide each node/element in a specific layer by its l2 norm (the square root of the sum of squared elements), and my assumption is that keras' l2_normalize can achieve this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/l2_normalize?version=stable. However, I am not sure how to actually use this since there are no examples in the documentation. I found other examples that use a lambda function along with it, for example `Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(previous_layer)`. However, I am not sure why this needs to be done? Would appreciate help on how `keras.backend.l2_normalize` should be used and why a lambda function might be needed. Thanks!

Here is how I'd want to be used:

```
autoencoder = Sequential()

# Encoder Layer
 autoencoder.add(Dense(encoded_dim, input_shape=(input_dim,), 
 activation='relu'))

# Normalization - Need help here!
# TODO: Add l2_normalize here 

# Decoder Layer
# TODO: Add final output layer here
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do as the example you mentioned. It's ok.

You need a `Layer` for every operation in the model, backend operations are no exception, and that's the reason for the `Lambda` layer. (Keras needs layers to do its magic).

```
import keras.backend as K

autoencoder.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1)))
```

If you are planning to get the encoder's output later for other things, I suggest you create the `encoder` and `decoder` as separate models:

```
encoder = Sequential()
#.... add encoder layers ....
#encoder.add(....)

decoder = Sequential()
#.... add decoder layers ....
#decoder.add(....)
```

Finally create the autoencoder as another model, for training:

```
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model

autoInput = Input(shape_of_the_encoder_input)
encodedData = encoder(autoInput)
decodedData = decoder(encodedData)

autoencoder = Model(autoInput, decodedData)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and apologies for not accepting sooner.